# Building a templated MVC+AJAX ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, mono

I have quite good experience in WebForms, but now I would like to go further for my next ASP.NET project. I want the UI of the new application to be **fully** customizable by the website administrator.

Currently, with WebForms, in order to modify only the appearence of a page/control within a custom template folder, one can do the following:

1. Define the .ascx/.aspx file in order to inherit from the proper class containing the logic
2. Let the application use `LoadControl` to load the control object from the dynamic file path

Examples of "modifying the appearence" can mean moving controls across the page, inverting a search box with its search button, and so on... I don't mean just edit CSS, fonts, icons, etc.

I haven't used MVC yet but I read a couple of tutorials. Here are a few question for further study:

1. Does MVC4 work with Mono well?
2. Does MVC support the concept of Master Page or something similar? I'd like to define a common layout for all pages and specialize the content of each page with an appropriate template. If not, what kind of construct can I use?
3. Does MVC come with built-in AJAX support? Otherwise, what free tools can I use for developing AJAX websites in MVC?
4. Does MVC support the concept of user controls? I would like to develop the view/controller logics and layout of a `login-with-facebook-or-any-other-openid` box separately from the page where it will be placed into, just like I do with .ascx files. How can I do that?

I have read about the Razor template engine and it seems a good starting point. In my case, I generally want to keep the view/controller logics "static" and allow the admin to only change appearence. So, for example, one can override the search box appearence but it will always trigger the same action doing the same thing (searching the database)

Comment: All in one kind of questions... don'y fit SO style. And you should really google about MVC first.

Comment: I did, but I'm still very confused. BTW I misphrased the 3rd point

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Does MVC4 work with Mono well?

From what I've heard ASP.NET MVC 4 works on Mono. Whether it works well I cannot say because I've never used MVC on Mono.

> 2) Does MVC support the concept of Master Page or something similar? I'd like to define a common layout for all pages and specialize the content of each page with an appropriate template. If not, what kind of construct can I use?

Yes, it supports master pages where views inherit from those master pages. If you are using the Razor view engine those Master pages are called Layouts.

> 3) Does MVC support AJAX? What free tools can I use for developing AJAX websites in MVC?

As you know AJAX is server side language agnostic. So of course that MVC supports AJAX. You could use [Visual Studio Express 2012 for web](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-web) as a free tool to develop ASP.NET MVC applications.

> 4) Does MVC support the concept of user controls? I would like to develop the view/controller logics and layout of a login-with-facebook-or-any-other-openid box separately from the page where it will be placed into, just like I do with .ascx files. How can I do that?

No user controls is something that no longer exists in MVC nor it is supported. If you would like to develop some reusable portions of page you could use partial views. And child actions. Phil Haack has a [nice blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) about child actions.